# OpenMP optimization for a function

Tags: c, optimization, openmp

We have been given an assignment on using openmp to optimize a poorly structured program. I am very new at programming so I hope anyone can shed some light on how to optimize this function (one of the many I need to optimize):

```
void
entry_type3(F2D *sData, F2D *ones, F2D *quat, F2D **pos, F2D **vel)
{
    //Observation

   F2D *t;

   t = fSetArray(1, 3, 0);
    asubsref(t,2) = -9.8;


    F2D *accl = fDeepCopyRange(sData, 0, 1, 0, 3);
    F2D *gtemp = fMtimes( ones, t);
    F2D *gravity = quatRot(gtemp, quat);



    fFreeHandle(gtemp);
    fFreeHandle(t);

   t = fSetArray(3,3,0);
    asubsref(t,0) = 1;
    asubsref(t,4) = 1;
    asubsref(t,8) = 1;

    int n = ones->height;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<(t->height*t->width); i++)
            asubsref(t,i) = asubsref(t,i)/STDDEV_ACCL;

   F2D *w = mcl( gravity, accl, t);

    generateSample(w, quat, *vel, *pos);
    fFreeHandle(t);


    //Motion model
  t = fMtimes(ones, accl);
    fFreeHandle(accl);
    accl = fMinus(t, gravity);
    fFreeHandle(w);
    fFreeHandle(gravity);
    fFreeHandle(t);




    F2D *is;
    #pragma omp parallel sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        {
            F2D *is = quatConj(quat);
            F2D *s = quatRot(*vel, is);
            fFreeHandle(is);
            for(i=0; i<(s->height*s->width); i++)
            {
                 asubsref(s,i) = asubsref(s,i)*acclTimeInterval;
            }
            is = fPlus(*pos, s);
            fFreeHandle(*pos);
            *pos = fDeepCopy(is);
            fFreeHandle(is);
            fFreeHandle(s);
         }


        /** pos_ above stores: pos+quatRot(vel,quatConj(quat))*acclTimeInterval **/

        #pragma omp section
        {
            F2D *is = quatConj(quat);
            F2D *s = quatRot(accl, is);
            F2D* t = fDeepCopy(s);

            for(i=0; i<(s->height*s->width); i++)
            {
                asubsref(t,i) = 1/2*asubsref(s,i)*acclTimeInterval*acclTimeInterval;
            }

            /** t_ above stores: 1/2*quatRot(accl,quatCong(quat))*acclTimeInterval^2 **/

            fFreeHandle(s);
            fFreeHandle(is);


 s = randnWrapper(n,3);

            for(i=0; i<(s->height*s->width); i++)
            {
                asubsref(s,i) = asubsref(s,i) * M_STDDEV_POS;
            }

            /** s_ above stores: randn(n,3)*M_STDDEV_POS **/

       is = fPlus(*pos, t);
           fFreeHandle(*pos);
         *pos = fPlus(is, s);

            fFreeHandle(s);
            fFreeHandle(t);
            fFreeHandle(is);
    } 

}        
        //vel=vel+accl*acclTimeInterval+randn(n,3)*M_STDDEV_VEL;
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
#pragma omp section
{
 F2D *t = fDeepCopy(accl);
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=0; i<(accl->height*accl->width); i++)
    {
            asubsref(t,i) = asubsref(accl,i) * acclTimeInterval;
    }

    is = fPlus(*vel, t);
    fFreeHandle(accl);
    fFreeHandle(t);
}
#pragma omp section
{

 F2D *s = randnWrapper(n,3);
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=0; i<(s->height*s->width); i++)
    {
            asubsref(s,i) = asubsref(s,i) * M_STDDEV_VEL;
    }

    fFreeHandle(*vel);
    *vel = fPlus(is, s);
    fFreeHandle(is);
    fFreeHandle(s);
}
}
}
```

I already added a few openmp parallels in but it is still running very slowly, so I was hoping if you seasoned veterans can point me to which spots I should be looking at to improve performance.

Comment: You are using OpenMP sections. Are you really sure, that codes in both sections (within each `section` construct) can execute independently of each other, i.e. there is no data dependency between them? Very slow execution is usually a sign of (false) sharing between threads.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, it looks like just stuck some `pragma`s in helter skelter, without concern for the parallel nature of the code. Right now, you aren't really splitting up the work over your processors, you are essentially duplicating effort by having each core do the same thing (and probably creating some severe wrong answers in the way). It would be nice to see the original, to see what you have changed. You actually need to split the task up programmatically (ie, if you were processing an image, you need to tell, say, processor one to do odd pixels and processor 2 to do even pixels, OpenMP isn't smart enough to figure that out). I'm sorry if that doesn't seem as helpful as it could be, but saying as this is for an assignment, I think you probably need to figure a certain amount out for yourself- but the important part is that OpenMP can't just make code parallel, you need to tell it how. Look into omp_get_num_threads() and omp_get_thread_num().

Comment: thank you that is actually very helpful, I was thinking the same thing (regarding im just putting in pragmas for the heck of it) the problem is I am having trouble seeing which parts can be run in parallel as the variables are all seemingly connected and should be executed one after the other, I am hoping for some tips on how to successfully split up the code mainly

Comment: So, I'm probably not going to give this the justice it deserves, but take a look at this bit here: `for(i=0; i<(s->height*s->width); i++){asubsref(s,i) = asubsref(s,i) * M_STDDEV_POS;}`. It doesn't look like this bit is terribly dependent on sequence (though there are ways of handling that- I'm just not terribly qualified to talk about them), so suppose I made it instead `int k=numProcessors; int MaxI=s->height*s->width;int procNum=processorNumber;for(int i=procNum;i<MaxI;i+=k){asubsref(s,i) = asubsref(s,i) * M_STDDEV_POS;}`. That will split up the work- I hope you see why.

Answer (score 0):

This code in the beginning:
`for(i=0; i<(t->height*t->width); i++)
            asubsref(t,i) = asubsref(t,i)/STDDEV_ACCL;`
could be effectively parallelized. Computations for each `i` are completely independent.

Look for such independent parts of code. And, of course, you should think what to parallelize.